# How do i add a comment to a particular google slide using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I have a google slide desk with three slides & i want to add a comment to each slide. I am able to reach to the slide using for loop (total rows in sheet is same as total number of slides, and slide i am using is the second slide onwards. so there is no problem with my loop)

```
 // open the slide using slide id
 var s=SlidesApp.openById(a.getId())
 for(let r=2; r<=4; r++){
    // get the current slide
    var currentSlide=s.getSlides()[r-1];
    var fileId = currentSlide.getObjectId();
    var slideUrl = a.getUrl()+"#slide=id."+fileId;
    var slideId = getIdFromUrl(slideUrl);
    var comment = {'content':'hi'};
    Drive.Comments.insert(comment, slideId);
  }

function getIdFromUrl(url) { return url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/); }
```

This code works but its adding the comment to the file and not to the individual slide. (*Note - For this code to work, we have to enable Drive in services in app script.) How can i add the comment to the individual slides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Answer:

Not possible.

#### Explanation:

It is currently not possible to add comments to a specific location in Google Documents (including Docs, Sheets, Slides). The ability for adding [anchored comments](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-comments#anchor) refers to non-Google Docs (e.g. images, PDFs) (listen to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBU52nacbLw&t=690s) for more details).

Therefore, you can only add comments unanchored comments, belonging to the whole file.

What's possible is responding to a located comment by retrieving its `id` and calling [Replies: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/replies/create).

#### Issue Tracker:

There are several feature requests for this in Issue Tracker, either about all of Google Docs editors or about a specific editor:

- [Provide read/write access to comments in Google Docs](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756056)
- [Ability to create comments in specific cells/ranges and assign them to someone](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160685101)
- [Provide ability to create a Drive API Comment anchor resource as method on DocumentApp selection class](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763384)

I'd suggest you to subscribe to some or all of these issues by [starring them](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue) and/or file a new feature request to tackle Slides specifically.

#### Related questions:

- [Creating anchored comments programmatically in Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23498275)
- [Google Drive API ignores anchor parameter when creating comments in a spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57511838)
- [How to match comments on an image using kix anchor (or not) in Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050342/how-to-match-comments-on-an-image-using-kix-anchor-or-not-in-google-docs)