# Issue adding comments on Google Doc (Done all the work required in retrieving comments from Google Doc)

Tags: dart, google-docs-api

Could you please help me with an issue I am having adding comments on Google Doc? I have done all the work required in retrieving comments from Google Drive. This is how I retrieve comments from Google Doc:

```
String fileId ='1up_-hN_z6Fv4NuPUDZioIzFgk42o4j6n8'; 

String commentId = "AAAAp8ow"; 

googleUser = await _googleUserSignIn.signIn(); 

final authHeaders = await googleUser!.authHeaders; 

final client = GoogleHttpClient(authHeaders); 

print(' passed 1 '); 

final marcoDrive = drive.DriveApi(client); 

var  result = await marcoDrive.comments.get(fileId, commentId, $fields: 'content');
```

The screenshot below shows the debugging results:

[image]

As you can see on the screenshot above, the results variable contains a comment data fetch from Google Doc. The screenshot below shows Google Doc and the orange circle is the comment:
[image]

My issue is creating a comment on Google Doc. I find the Comment request parameter, highlighted below using an orange arrow, problematic as I am struggling to create a comment in Google Doc.

var result2 = await marcoDrive.comments.create(request, fileId, $fields: 'content: data is data');

[image]

Could you please help me to understand what the Comment request parameter means and how to use it? I would also appreciate it if you could help me understand how to anchor comments.

The programming language I'm using is Dart. Here is a link that I used to help me understand how to manage Google Drive Doc comments: (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to supply a Comment resource as your request body, as you can see at the official docs: [Comments.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/create#request-body).

Here are the fields corresponding to the [Comment resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments#resource). The only required field is `content`.

The JSON representation would be something like:

```
{
  "content": "YOUR COMMENT"
}
```

In Dart, it would probably be something along the following lines:

```
Comment request = Comment();
request.content = "YOUR COMMENT";
var result = await marcoDrive.comments.create(request, fileId, $fields);
```

#### Library reference:

- [create method](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/drive.v3/CommentsResource/create.html)
- [Comment class](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/drive.v3/Comment-class.html)
- [Comment constructor](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/drive.v3/Comment/Comment.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for you help and greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as drive;              
     var request = drive.Comment();
     request.content = 'Law of Conservation of Energy';
     var result2 = await marcoDrive.comments.create(request, fileId, $fields: 'content');

Comment: @Lamblichus,  If I want to anchor a specific word in a sentence, do I use the same way I used for request.content but instead request.anchor?

Comment: For example:                                                                                           
      request.content = 'Energy != thermodynamics';
     request.anchor ='Testing';
     var result2 = await marcoDrive.comments.create(request, fileId, $fields: 'content');

Comment: @AdanTabari Unfortunately, comments created via API cannot be anchored to a specific part of the Google Docs (this parameter is used for non-Google Docs) (see, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67019897)).